# Cannot run test cases using rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubymine, ruby-2.3

I am using ruby version 2.3.1 and rubymine version 8.0.1. It shows error like following when I try to run test cases

Screenshot1: Run test case using following way
[image]

Screenshot2: Error when I run test cases 
[image]

Comment: rubymine 8.0.1? Isn't it quite old? I have not seen that version scheme for a long time. The current version is  2016.2.4. Have you tried updating?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: Now I updated rubymine to version 2016.2.4. Now I get the error like "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)"

Comment: Can't help you here. I myself don't run tests from rubymine.